Apostrophes around the title in the references
Does someone know how to set these apostrophes around the chapters in a reference like in the example below?
Mohd, T.K. et al. (2023) ‘Analyzing Strengths and Weaknesses of Modern Game Engines’, International Journal of Computer Theory and Engineering, 15(1), pp. 54–60. Available at: https://doi.org/10.7763/IJCTE.2023.V15.1330.
Current settings
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=3,urldate=long,innamebeforetitle, articlein=false]{biblatex}

My approach would be like something like this:
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{' \fancyCommandForTitle '}}

Thanks for the help

Could you give us a bib file to start from?  Do you care how the citation appears in the main article?

Do you use BibTeX and a package like natbib, or do you use biblatex? Or are you currently using neither, but free to use whatever you like? At least if you are already using something, please show a minimal working example with bibliography that shows what you are currently having.

quotation marks around article titles is default with authoryear, at least. but you are using non-standard package options. either you get an error or you're using code you've not shown to define them.  if I remove those options and minimally complete your document, I get the expected output, including quotation marks. which quotation marks you get depends on the currently active language and whether you've loaded csquotes and language support, including any relevant variant support. the approach you suggest will definitely not get good results - not, at least, in most languages.
